# About a line in a TV drama which is hard to understand

Tags: phrases, listening

In the 2nd episode of "Tokyo Love Story", from 26:55 to 27:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNW0VEvfIbU#t=26m50s

「いやだね、この？」

What is the word/phrase after 「この」?

Comment: It sounds a little bit like 「人間キャッチボール」. Anyway, I am very unsure about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like 人間キャッチホン (or 人間キャッチフォン) to me. [キャッチホン](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/service/communication/catch_phone/) is the Japanese term for ["call waiting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_waiting).

I haven't watched the full episode, but this would make sense in context if Satomi (the woman in the apron) is "putting Mikami on hold" while she gets closer to Nagao, or something to that effect.

The meaning of this idiom is pretty transparent (once you know what キャッチホン means), but I have no idea whether it is common - hopefully a native speaker and/or person who lives in Japan can chime in. There are about a dozen Google results for [`"人間キャッチホン"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BA%BA%E9%96%93%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3%22) and about a dozen more for [`"人間キャッチフォン"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BA%BA%E9%96%93%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%22), for what it's worth.

Comment: +1. I don't think this is common, and most of the Google results of "人間キャッチホン" seem to refer to this episode. And NTT's キャッチホン (and similar services by other companies) are now much less popular than in 1980's...